# Count number of observations and their percentages in SAS

Tags: sas

I'm new to SAS so looking for advices/ideas here..

Essentially I want to create summary table/report containing number of observations, percentages of certain group and means.

Consider the following example:

```
A/C No   Status   DaysToStatus
1        Suspend  10
2        Blocked  20
3
4        Suspend  20
```

My intended output/report is something like:

```
Average Days To Suspend    Average Days to Blocked    % Suspend    %Blocked
15                         20                         50%          25%
```

I can do the average easily using Proc Report function but I am struggling to incorporate the observations and its percentages even with Compute function.

Any ideas on how I go about in doing this?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't posted your code, so approach might not be the same as yours. I don't think you need `compute`. Build your report with three columns: status (group), daystostatus mean, and the `pctn` statistic to count the rows. Use the `missing` option in the `proc report` statement to base the percentage on the total including those with a missing status.

```
proc report data=yourdata missing nowd;
  column status daystostatus pctn;
  define status / group;
  define daystostatus / analysis mean 'Avg days to status';
  define pctn / 'Pct of total' format=percent10.;
run;
```

Comment: By far a better solution than I suggested. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Preparing the data first

```
        data have;
        Number = 1;
        Status = 'Suspend';
        DaysToStatus = 10;
        output;
        Number = 2;
        Status = 'Blocked';
        DaysToStatus = 20;
        output;
        Number = 3;
        Status = '';
        DaysToStatus =.;
        output;
        Number = 4;
        Status = 'Suspend';
        DaysToStatus =20;
        output;
        run;
```

This should work for you:

```
            data want;
            set have end = eof;
            if Status='Suspend' then do;
                sum_suspend+DaysToStatus;
                count_suspend+1;
            end;
            else if status='Blocked' then do;
                sum_blocked+DaysToStatus;
                count_blocked+1;
            end;
            total_sum+DaysToStatus;
            total_count = _n_;
            Average_Days_To_Suspend = sum_suspend / count_suspend;
            Average_Days_To_blocked = sum_blocked / count_blocked;
            percent_suspend = count_suspend/total_count;
            percent_blocked = count_blocked/total_count;
            if eof;
            drop n status number DaysToStatus sum_: count_: total_:;
            run;
```

Answer (score 1):

proc sql;

select 
   sum(case when status eq 'Suspend' then DaysToStatus else 0 end)/sum(case when  status eq 'Suspend' then DaysToStatus else 0 end) as
   avg_days_to_suspend,

sum(case when status eq 'Blocked' then DaysToStatus else 0 end)/
   sum(case when status eq 'Blocked' then DaysToStatus else 0 end) as
   avg_days_to_blocked,

sum(case when status eq 'Suspend' then DaysToStatus else 0
   end)/sum(DaysToStatus) as percent_suspend format = percent7.0,

sum(case when status eq 'Blocked' then DaysToStatus else 0
   end)/sum(DaysToStatus) as percent_blocked format = percent7.0

from work.in_ds; /* replace work.in_ds with your own data set */

quit;